# Looking to run QGIS basics course, are there any legal requirements?

Tags: qgis

I've been asked by several people to run a QGIS basics course as there is a real demand for some of our subcontractors to be able to manipulate their own data but at a very simple level.
My question is, where QGIS is open source software, are there any requirements for the course to be verified or certified? If so, what is the process?

Comment: Consider donating to the project. Every time i give a course, i donate a certain amount to the project. Avantages: #1 You will be listed in the (imo quite short) donors list. #2 You do sth good ;)

Comment: and encourage your students to donate too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, nothing, none, zero, zilch, nada.

You can teach whatever you like using Qgis. Obviously you cant claim to have any certification or verification unless you have it. But I don't think for Qgis such a thing even exists.

Most Free and Open Source licenses have no restriction on use - so if you want to use Qgis to locate your nuclear missiles in order to blow up fluffy kittens, you can.

Comment: `Qgis to locate your nuclear missiles in order to blow up fluffy kittens, you can` but don't because we all love fluffy kittens.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no restrictions.

There may be some issues if you use their logo or imply that the organization behind QGIS is involved or approve of what you're doing (with out them actually supporting it).

But with open source software there is 0 restrictions on you starting Nick's QGIS Class.

Comment: but you can still use logo to imply that you use official QGIS release etc..

Comment: I'd probably drop them a line on their mailing list first before using their logo but I'd be shocked about them doing anything but asking you to stop nicely about anything you did in good faith.